# Android - Go back and finish activity

Tags: android-intent

I have activity A and activity B. I call activity B from A, and when I want to go back by my phone, I must to click several times because several windows of B is created.
thank you in advance

Comment: What is your question? It sounds like you only want to create one instance of activity B. If so, please look up the `launchMode` activity parameter in the documentation for `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you starting Activity B from Activity A? If you want to close Activity A, start activity B using `StartActivity` and then call `finish()` on Activity A.

If you need only one instance of B, then use [FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT) in StartActivity. This will not create a new instance of Activity B if it is already running.